# Apple ID problem

Tags: iphone, ipad, apple-id

I am just wondering I already have an apple ID created on my iPad and I recently got an iPhone I am wondering if I keep the same apple ID for my iPhone will everything I download on my iPad come up on my phone? (like apps and music)

Comment: this article might help http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204074 and this https://www.apple.com/support/appleid/basics/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control exactly what gets automatically downloaded. Settings > iTunes & App Store > the "Automatic Downloads" section. You can toggle which media types you want to have automatically pushed to the device.

Comment: Thank you very much.If I didn't do that process would the things downloaded on ipad come up on my iPhone?

Comment: I'm not sure what the default setting is. I'm inclined to say "yes" from experience with my mom's iPhone, but it can't hurt to go into your iPhone's settings and confirm it.